# How to make sure Uniqueness of Constants values in Java Class in development phase?

Tags: java, constants, development-environment

Our team have a shared `Java class` only for Constant values
When any developer need to add a constant
He will add a record in this class

```
public class Constants_Class {

    public static final String Constant1 = "value1";
    public static final String Constant2 = "value2";
    public static final String Constant3 = "value3";

    // Need to prevent that in Development time - NOT Run time
    public static final String Constant4 = "value1"; // value inserted before

}
```

The problem is that
We need in Development time prevent any developer
To add a new constant its value inserted before
// Need Unique Constants Value(s)
Any suggestions ??

Comment: Why not use enums? That would eliminate the use of Strings as artificial constants. This is what enums were built to do. The enums should be part of the package that uses them, and enums for each section will have their own name-space.

Comment: Ctrl+F might help you also? Enum is the way to go, of course.

Comment: enum would be easier, another option would be a read only dictionary, you'd need a bit more of a reason than this though, and a unit test or two.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But also Enum accept insert 2 constants with the same value for example Constant3("value3"), Constant4("value3");

Comment: @ZiyaoWei we need it System maintained NOT by developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're asking at development time would require parsing the code, essentially duplicating compilation.  So it makes sense to let it be compiled and create a unit test to perform your check, then set up the project so that unit test is run each time the code base is compiled.  I'm pretty sure the most common unit test library in use is [JUnit](http://junit.org).

To easily check uniqueness of values, you can use the [Set.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) method, which returns false if the item being added already exists in the set:

```
@Test
public class TestConstantUniqueness() {
    Set<String> stringValues = new HashSet<String>();
    for (MyConstantEnum value : MyConstantEnum.values()) {
        String s = value.stringValue();
        Assert.assertTrue(
            "More than one constant in " + MyConstantEnum.class
                + " has the string value \"" + s + "\"",
            stringValues.add(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You really should be using [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). This will solve the problem you're seeing.

You can also associate `String` values with enums:

```
public enum MyEnums {

    Constant1("value1"),
    Constant2("value2"),
    Constant3("value3");

    private String value;

    MyEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then you can do `MyEnum.Constant1.getValue()`.

Comment: But also Enum accept insert 2 constants with the same value  
for example  
`Constant3("value3"),
    Constant4("value3");`